# How to get number of sharing rules in VF page

Tags: visualforce, apex

I want to get number of sharing rules(Owner) and Sharing Rules (Criteria) to be displayed on Visual Force page. Can someone help me..?

Comment: can you share your current code that you have tried so far.. it will help us to suggest what to be changed/added.